# App Engine NDB query with multiple inequalities?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The only two answers on here involve essentially restructuring the database to accommodate this limitation, but I am unsure how to do that in my case.

I have a list of thousands of contacts, each with many many properties. I'm making a page that has an ability to filter on multiple properties at once.

For example: Age < 15, Date Added > 15 days ago, Location == Santa Cruz, etc. Potentially a ton of inequality filters required. How does one achieve this in GAE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs (for python)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries),

> Limitations: The Datastore enforces some restrictions on queries.
>   Violating these will cause it to raise exceptions. **For example,
>   combining too many filters, using inequalities for multiple
>   properties, or combining an inequality with a sort order on a
>   different property are all currently disallowed**. Also filters
>   referencing multiple properties sometimes require secondary indexes to
>   be configured.

If you check back in a few months, this may change. GAE keeps changing pretty quickly.

For now, though, you'll have to make multiple queries and combine them in your code.

Comment: This is what I started doing, but I was hoping somebody would come up with a more clever solution. :P